# Does the PlayStation2 official microphone offer good audio quality?

Tags: microphone

I want to record some stuff without too much noise.  I have two PS2 microphones (they came with the Singstar game I think) somewhere.

Do they offer sufficient audio recording quality?  If someone had a recorded example, it would be awesome.

If it is good, does using the USB adapter change something (I don't have a 6.3 > 3.5 mm jack adapter)?

I know not everybody has the same requirements concerning audio quality; for me, something like broadcast radio FM is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally i did dig up those microphones to test them. They appear to do just fine , i don't really know the audio terms but there is a little blank noise in the background but at a really low level.

Using jack (finally they are 3.5) or USB doesn't make difference (at least for me) except the fact that usb got two input so it can be stereo .

Answer (score 2):

"Good quality" is a very vague thing where microphones are concerned, and with audio in general. While you can assume that those mics, marketed as they are towards videogames, are likely to be cheaply produced under loose design requirements, it may very well be that those mics are good enough for your purposes. They *do* work for their games after all, and even the cheapest mics are generally good enough for what people need them for.

If you have two of them already, the best test for whether they'll work for you is just to try them out and see! Make your own recordings and see if you like them.

Regarding your second question, the USB adapter is a built-in audio interface, which performs preamplification and digital conversion. Such processes do have an effect on audio quality, although it can be fairly subtle compared to the characteristics of the mic itself. If you're really asking whether or not you can use it, the answer is "yes." Again, you have it already, so you can just give it a try.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the vague of quality terms. The reasons i was asking i because i didn't want to dig out boxes to search the mic if it was not suitable for my need , bu i guess i have no choice :p. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I have used a pair of singstar microphones in a home studio set up and found them to be great for my needs. I have them connected via the USB connector direct into to a win 8.1 PC. You need to go in and change the PC settings to see both microphones. Once configured you can record directly into audacity as a stereo take. The recording seems a bit trebly but using the effects in audacity can correct some of that.

Answer (score 0):

It's really bad even after editing in audacity its still not good. Too much background noise, all in all i dont like it example: https://www.youtube.com/user/DaRKHuNTeRMK/videos
everything here is recorded with that microphone